# Can't display image on the listView using setImageUri

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, android-room

I save user's image uri as string in my RoomDatabase.
and this is all I've got I have no idea how to overcome this error and show display the image into the RecyclerView,I've read some things about bitmap and etcetra but couldn't understand or code with them.

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

Student current = students.get(position);
holder.nameItemView.setText(current.getName());
holder.numberItemView.setText(current.getNumber());

 ///here!
Uri uri = Uri.parse(current.getImagePath());
    holder.studImage.setImageURI(uri);

}
```

on the listView it doesn't display the image.
I checked the debugger and saw this error:

```
ava.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{5ca0d63 20181:com.example.android.studmanagedbtrain/u0a92} (pid=20181, uid=10092) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
W/ImageView: Unable to open content: content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A42
             java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A42
                 at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1396)
                 at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1247)
                 at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:967)
                 at android.widget.ImageView.getDrawableFromUri(ImageView.java:951)
                 at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:922)
                 at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:531)
                 at .
                   etc.
                   etc.
                 .
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
             resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A42
```

Answer (score 2):

use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library to load images as follows:

```
 Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageUrl).into(promotionImageView)
```

Comment: how can i declar mContext in my adapter?
i added "private Context mContext" on top of the adapter but the app crashes

Comment: you can get context from image as promotionImageView.getContext()

Comment: ava.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{5ca0d63 20181:com.example.android.studmanagedbtrain/u0a92} (pid=20181, uid=10092) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)

Comment: In the new `Picasso` version you don't need `.with(context)`, just use `Picasso.get().load(current.getImagePath()).into(studImage)`

Comment: Using Picasso wont change anything. It says in the error its a permission issue. please look at Jessica's answer

Answer (score 2):

> There may be issue with your way of getting Uri from file

```
 Uri Uri = getUriFromFilePath(MainActivity.this, PhotoFilePath);

 public Uri getUriFromFilePath(Context ctx, File filePath) {
        Uri requirdUri = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            requirdUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctx,
                    ctx.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + PROVIDER_FILE_EXTENSION,
                    filePath);
        } else {
            requirdUri = Uri.fromFile(filePath);
        }

        return requirdUri;
    }
```

> Create paths file in Resource--> xml 
>       res/xml/paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <root-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/storage/"/>
</paths>
```

> Add provider in manifest.xml file inside application tag

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.demo.example.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
</provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this,

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/"+R.drawable.image);
imgView.setImageURI(null); 
imgView.setImageURI(uri);
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso library to efficiently load the image from url.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below method

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
```